# Control Proguard slimming of methods in Android

Tags: android, function, methods, proguard, slim

I am using Eclipse and the built of ProGuard included with the latest Android release, trying to obfuscate my android app but it keeps removing important methods.  I have tried editing the proguard.cfg file to keep the methods by typing various exclusions, such as the following

- keep public void myMethod(String myString)
- keep public class myInterface
- keep public class com.help.app.myInterface.**

but none of these are working.  When I look in the usage.txt file the methods are still there and my app doesn't function.  I do not understand what I am doing wrong.  I would appreciate some help.

Here is what my class looks like

```
package com.whoiam.whatido;

public class MainClass extends Activity {
    ......
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ....

    }

    ....
    ....

    final class myInterface {

        myInterface() {}    

        public void dontDeleteMePlease(String message) {
            ....

        }
        public void leaveMeBe(String message) {
            ...

        }


        .....

    }
    final class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        @Override 
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view) {
            ....
        }
}
```

Here is an example of my proguard.cfg file (it is default except for the three 'keep' near the middle):

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keep public class com.whoiam.whatido.myInterface.**

-keep public class com.whoiam.whatido.myInterface.** {
    <methods>;}

-keep public void leaveMeBe(String message);

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>; }

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context,
android.util.AttributeSet); }

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context,
android.util.AttributeSet, int); }

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String); }

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {   public
static final
android.os.Parcelable$Creator *; }
```

I also tried -dontshrink since I don't really want my code slashed... but alas it shrinks anyway.  I have also tried as many variations as I can think of for hours on end, but nothing saves my methods.

How do I save my "donDontDeleteMePlease" from ProGuard's wrath? What do I need to type into that proguard.cfg file to make it like me?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
-keep class com.whoiam.whatido.MainClass$myInterface {
  public void dontDeleteMePlease(java.lang.String);
  public void leaveMeBe(java.lang.String);
}
```

Note that the inner class is specified with a `$` and that it is not public.

You can find more information and examples in the [ProGuard manual](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/index.html).

Comment: For a moment I thought it worked.  But it still doesn't preserve the functions.  I'd like to stop slimming all together, but that doesn't seem to work.  I've read through their manual and come up short.  It looks to me like it is cutting out the com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService that google tells it to keep.  Very stubborn, it should be this hard :)  Thanks for the help and if you have any additional thoughts please let me know.